# Workbook to close if passwords were incorrect

Tags: excel, vba

In case a user enters a worng password I want the workbook to close down without saving. However, the code I'm trying does not work.

```
Sub Unhide()

mypass = Application.InputBox( _
prompt:="Enter password - In case of wrong password please close the file 
and try again")


If mypass = "BJE" Then Sheets("Overview").Visible = True
If mypass = "BFL" Then Sheets("BFL").Visible = True
If mypass = "EBR" Then Sheets("EBR").Visible = True
If mypass = "DME" Then Sheets("DME").Visible = True
If mypass = "AJA" Then Sheets("AJA").Visible = True
If mypass = "RLC" Then Sheets("RLC").Visible = True
If mypass = "JMK" Then Sheets("JMK").Visible = True
If mypass = "AXB" Then Sheets("AXB").Visible = True
If mypass = "JIK" Then Sheets("JIK").Visible = True
If mypass = "KKO" Then Sheets("KKO").Visible = True

If mypass <> "BJE" Or "BFL" Or "EBR" Or "DME" Or "AJA" Or "RLC" Or "JMK" 
Or "AXB" Or "JIK" Or "KKO" Then ThisWorkbook.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: Use a `Select Case` here. You have to repeat the `mypass <>` for each `Or`, and it's already lengthy.

Comment: Why would you ask the user to reopen the file to try again? Why not showing a message to try again until you get the password right or click cancel to close the workbook?

Comment: I tried that but found that to be way above my skills, sadly. Do you know, how I could implement this? I tried to implement it as an 'if else statement', but without luck

Comment: Going to suggest a different approach, which will cut down your overall code significantly... use a variant array with the names of your sheets.  Loop through the array and if you have any matches, then pass the arr(i) to the visible function, otherwise display a msgbox saying incorrect password then redisplay the prompt afterwards.

Comment: @Cyril - that is a good idea, except for the case of `BJE`, which corresponds to the `Overview` sheet, so you'd have to tweak the approach slightly. Maybe a dictionary.

Comment: @BigBen true, though you can have a the array be the passwords and have a separate check for sheets("overview").  will end up being similar to your answer with the select case being used, but would have less... guess i'll mock it up as an answer

Comment: @Cyril I'm wondering if the passwords are the sheet names or if this is just sample data... That said, mocking up a loop to reprompt until you get the right password would be a great answer.

Comment: @BigBen i was thinkign similarly, in which case 2 arrays would be perfrect... one for passwords and one for sheets

Comment: Just so you're aware, you shouldn't be trusting this for any security purposes. The user can always pause execution of the VBA, then hide/unhide whatever sheets they want. Even if the workbook/worksheet is password protected, cracking that is extremely easy (see the related posts for this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to repeat the `mypass <>` for each `String` you're checking.

```
If mypass <> "BJE" Or mypass <> "BFL" Or mypass <> "EBR"...
```

That's cumbersome. Use `Select Case` and `Case Else` to close.

```
Select Case myPass
    Case "BJE"
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Visible = True ' Or use the sheet code name
    Case "BFL"
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BFL").Visible = True

    ... ' and so on

    Case Else
         ThisWorkbook.Close ' though as pointed out, this is a pretty harsh user experience
End Select
```